# Angularjs ng-repeat in views vs for loop in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Okay. So now I came across this situation. Say if I have a complex object and I need to loop through the object and calculate few arithmetic operations. As of now I am not going to store those values in the back end, it is just for display purpose.

Is it better to use ng-repeat and ng-if in the view or use for loop and if condition in the controller? I mean which one will perform better? Or both are in the same boat?

Comment: The `for` loop and mapping properties would probably be better. The view will be constantly evaluated each `$digest` cycle. Depending on the size of the data, either could work.

Answer (score 1):

When you read about how to optimize AngularJS applications, as on this article for example : https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135, you will almost everytime read that you have to avoid ng-repeat as much as possible.

So, to answer to your question, keep the ng-repeat for the cases you really can't do another way (this happens quite often).

About the ng-if, you have to know that it destroys/reconstruct the concerned part of the DOM, so, if you don't have to dynamically show/hide items, avoid it also.

Good luck !